# Cell Statistics cutting off raster output at north, south, and west edges using ArcGIS Pro

Tags: coordinate-system, arcgis-pro, spatial-analyst, cell-statistics

I am trying to add five partially overlapping rasters using Cell Statistics in ArcGIS Pro 2.3.2 (Windows 7). The north, south, and west edges of the output raster are getting abruptly cut off, even though the input rasters extend to the edges of the grey outline (see red circled areas in image). All the input rasters are in the same projected coordinate system (CRTM05) and resolution (30m). I've tried rearranging the order of the input rasters in the Cell Statistics tool, in case that made a difference, but that didn't do anything. I have set the snap raster and mask to a raster of the entire study area, with the same resolution and coordinate system.

Why does it keep cutting off the edges?

[image]

Comment: Try setting extent to Union of inputs.

Comment: Thank you, that worked!